# Configuring typeorm from node js to an AWS lambda - get 'No metadata for {myTable} was found'

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, typeorm

Hi I have a node js project that I then upload to an AWS lambda.
Inside this project I am using typeorm to connect to my database.
Everything I code in TS is built and compiled into one big index.js file which is the only thing I upload to the lambda.

In src/classes/Entities.ts I have (among others) the following entity:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, PrimaryColumn, Column, OneToMany, ManyToOne, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('silo')
export class Silo {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
    name: string;

    @Column({ type: 'int', nullable: true })
    searchEngineId: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255, nullable: true })
    siloType: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    primaryKeywordLabel: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    domain: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    rootPageUrl: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    rootPageLabel: string;

    @OneToMany(() => SiloLevel, (siloLevel) => siloLevel.silo, {cascade: true})
    levels: SiloLevel[];

    @OneToMany(() => SiloSecondaryKeyword, (secondaryKeyword) => secondaryKeyword.silo, {cascade: true})
    secondaryKeywords: SiloSecondaryKeyword[];
}
```

In the src/db/dbConnections.ts file I have the following code:

```
    export const dataSource = new DataSource({
      type: "postgres",
      username: DB_USER,
      host: DB_HOST,
      database: DB_NAME,
      password: DB_PASSWORD,
      port: +DB_PORT,
      entities: [require("../classes/Entities"), Silo, SiloLevel, SiloSecondaryKeyword, SiloLevelSiloLevel],
      namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy()
    });

    dataSource.initialize()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Data Source has been initialized!")
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error during Data Source initialization", err)
        });
```

When I run locally (so TS code) without the require("../classes/Entities") it works fine, this require is a fix I tried from the web. I suppose the problem is when switching to JS it does not know the entites anymore as type. The only file I get when compiloing to JS is index.js outside my src in dist/ folder.

When I test my lambda I get the following error:

```
    START RequestId: a44fbe84-e847-4e76-a692-a88dcaca56ec Version: $LATEST
    2023-06-12T14:21:46.553Z    a44fbe84-e847-4e76-a692-a88dcaca56ec    ERROR             
    EntityMetadataNotFoundError2: No metadata for "Silo" was found.
        at DataSource2.getMetadata (/var/task/index.js:114467:17)
        at get metadata [as metadata] (/var/task/index.js:55353:40)
        at Repository2.find (/var/task/index.js:55535:39)
        at getSilos (/var/task/index.js:150770:31)
        at getAllSilos (/var/task/index.js:150813:24)
        at Runtime.handler (/var/task/index.js:151089:29)
        at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1086:29)
    END RequestId: a44fbe84-e847-4e76-a692-a88dcaca56ec
    REPORT RequestId: a44fbe84-e847-4e76-a692-a88dcaca56ec  Duration: 212.97 ms Billed Duration:   
    213 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 113 MB Init Duration: 622.82 ms
```

I tried adding require to "entities" in the datasource connection options,
I tried also writing something like __dirname + '../classes/Entities{.js,.ts}
I tried writing __dirname + '../../dist/index.js

Comment: I tried now seperating each of my entities into a different file in entities folder, still no luck. In the end in JS everything is seperated and compiled to index.js

Comment: try replacing this in your DataSource config  for the entities property => entities:[path.join(__dirname, 'classes/Entities/*.ts'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'classes/Entities/*.js')]

Comment: Also it's not a good practice to have all your entities crawled up in a single file, I recommend splitting them all into different files.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that the database connection is not initialized before you are using it, seems to be a common issue with the default TypeORM setup recommendation and Lambda. You can await the connection on Lambda start

```
exports.handler = async (event: any, context: any) => {
    if(!AppDataSource.isInitialized)
        await AppDataSource.initialize();
    return serverlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
};
```